# Why does putting Backbone and Handlebar's context into initialize function remove error?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope, handlebars.js, block

I'm pretty sure this is a general JS question and not just limited to Backbone but I encountered this as I was learning Backbone. In the first example below, I don't get an error but that's not the same for the 2nd example. Can you explain what is going on behind the scenes that makes Chrome Dev Tools show the error in the latter example but not the first. My best guess is that when something is in a function (such as initialize), it doesn't get run right away as the browser is reading the script whereas if it's part of the class being defined (in this case, app.ItemView), the object context needs to be completed so the browser will need to read through this.model#get in order to build the context object.

```
app.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.context = {
            title: this.model.get("title"),
            completed: this.model.get("completed")
        }
    }
});
```

vs.

```
app.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    context: {
        title: this.model.get("title"),
        completed: this.model.get("completed")
    }
});
```

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined*

**edit: it also doesn't work if the context in the first example isn't being defined appropriately -**

```
app.ItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.context.title = this.model.get("title");
        this.context.completed = this.model.get("completed");
        this.render();
    }
});
```

*Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** Corrected explanation of `this` after reading `mu is too short`'s comment.

The main reason for the error is that `this` in your second piece of code could refer to `window` or the caller of a function where `Backbone.View.extend` is being called.

That object doesn't have a `model` property, so it's `undefined` and calling `get` on `undefined` results in the error.

You need to make `initialize` a function because it will presumably be called by a Backbone.View object, which does have the `model` property available to it. In that context, `this` would refer to the Backbone.View object.

Comment: `this` in the second example is whatever it is outside the `extend` call (probably `window` in a browser), it won't be the `{ context: { ... } }` object that is being passed to `extend`.

Comment: this is a dumb question but even if something isn't defined yet, like in the first example, javascript will be ok with it? so if "this" is referring to the window, then it won't work, but in the initialize method, isn't the "this" referring to an instance object that hasn't been created yet? why doesn't javascript throw an error then?

Comment: I think because the function can be executed under different objects (for example, by using `bind` or by assigning the function to a property in another object), any instance of `this` in the body isn't evaluated until the function runs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#As_an_object_method